Ergodic series converge to the expectation?
Let $(X_i, Y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real-valued stochastic process. We say that $X$ is mean-ergodic, if $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\to \mathbb{E}X_1$$ in probability as $n\to\infty$.
Let $S_n:=\{i\in\{1, \dots, n\}: Y_i\in D \}$ where $D$ is some measurable set with $P(Y_i\in D)>0$.
If $(X_i, Y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ are mean-ergodic + strictly stationary, does it imply that
$$\frac{1}{|S_n|}\sum_{i\in S_n}X_i\to \mathbb{E}[X_1\mid Y_1\in D] $$
in probability as $n\to\infty$?
I am thinking about the following approach. Let $\tilde{Y}_i := 1[Y_i\in D]$ and let $W_i:=X_i\tilde{Y}_i$. Now,
$$
\frac{1}{|S_n|} \sum_{i\in S_n}X_i =    \bigg( \frac{n}{\sum_{i\leq n}\tilde{Y}_i}\bigg)   \bigg( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i\leq n}W_i    \bigg) . 
$$
The first part converges to $1/P(Y_1\in D)$. Does the second part converge to its expectation? As @Michael showed, NO. Hence, function of mean-ergodic series is not a mean-ergodic series. However, if we assume ergodicity in the sense of ''the underlying shift operator is an ergodic transformation'', is it sufficient assumption for the convergence to hold?

Great counter-example by Michael. Essentially this boils down to the fact that if $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are two sequences of random variables satisyfing the Strong Law of Large Numbers (what you call being mean-ergodic), then $(X_n Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ need not satisfy the Strong Law of Large Numbers.
More is true: If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are both stationary and ergodic, $(X_n Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ need neither be stationary nor satisfy the Strong Law of Large Numbers. For counter-examples, see for instance this MathOverflow answer by Martin Hairer.
Finally, if $((X_n,Y_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a stationary real-valued ergodic process, then so is $(X_n Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. I will provide a sketch of proof (which I surprisingly did not find upon a quick internet search): Let the shift operator for the $(X_n,Y_n)$'s on their canonical space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ be denoted by $\tau$ and the one for the $X_nY_n$'s on their canonical space $(\tilde\Omega,\tilde{\mathcal A},\tilde{\mathbb P})$ be denoted by $\tilde\tau$. Let $T:\Omega^2\to\tilde\Omega$ be given by $((x_n,y_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}\mapsto (x_n y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Then I claim that

$\tilde\Omega=T(\Omega^2)$,
$\tilde{\mathcal A}=\{B\subset\tilde\Omega:T^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A\}$,
$\tilde{\mathbb P}(B)=\mathbb P(T^{-1}(B))$ for all $B\in\tilde{\mathcal A}$,
$T\circ\tau\circ T^{-1}(\tilde\omega)=\{\tilde\tau(\tilde\omega)\}$ for $\tilde{\mathbb P}$ almost all $\tilde\omega\in\tilde\Omega$. (I consider $T\circ\tau\circ T^{-1}$ as a set-valued map, just as I do $T^{-1}$.)

From now, let $B\in\tilde{\mathcal A}$ be a $\tilde\tau$-invariant set. We want to show that $\tilde{\mathbb P}(B)\in\{0,1\}$. We have by claim 4. (with an abuse of notation, identifying $x\mapsto \{f(x)\}$ and $x\mapsto f(x)$ as the same function)
$$B=\tilde\tau^{-1}(B)=(T\circ\tau\circ T^{-1})^{-1}(B) = T\circ\tau^{-1}\circ T^{-1}(B),$$
from which we deduce
$$T^{-1}(B)=\tau^{-1}\circ T^{-1}(B),$$
thus establishing that $T^{-1}(B)$ is $\tau$-invariant.
By assumption, $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P, \tau)$ is ergodic, so $\mathbb P(T^{-1}(B))\in\{0,1\}$. By Claim 3. it follows that $\tilde{\mathbb P}(B)\in\{0,1\}$, thus establishing that $(\tilde\Omega,\tilde{\mathcal A},\tilde{\mathbb P},\tilde\tau)$ is also ergodic.
(It should be noted that this idea easily extends to more general transformations than $(x,y)\mapsto xy$.)

Max, thanks for the answer. So basically you are saying that if $((X_n,Y_n)){n\in\mathbb N}$ is a stationary +ergodic real-valued process, then $(W_n){n\in\mathbb N}$ is ergodic which implies $(W_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is mean-ergodic? The implication ergodic $\implies$ mean-ergodic follows from Birkhoff extension theorem right?

@AlbertParadek Yes I agree with everything you said (except I think you mean the Birkhoff ergodic Theorem). Of course the $(W_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ also need to be integrable otherwise mean-ergodicity is ill-defined.

I also wonder, there must be some general result that a function of ergodic series is an ergodic series, I guess as long as the function is surjective. But I cant find any reference for it even though it seems as an important result

@AlbertParadek I was having the same issue of not finding a reference. It seems that my proof can be adapted fairly generally to measurable transformations (I don't think that they need to be surjective).

Consider the counter-example:

$U \sim Unif[0,1]$.
$\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. $Bern(1/2)$ (and independent of $U$)

For all positive integers $n$ define
$$X_n=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} U & \mbox{ if $Y_n=1$} \\ 1-U & \mbox{ if $Y_n=0$}\end{array}\right.$$ with $D=\{1\}$.

Then

$E[Y_1]=E[X_1]=\frac{1}{2}$.

By the LLN we almost surely have $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\rightarrow 1/2$.

For all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(U1_{\{Y_i=1\}} + (1-U)1_{\{Y_i=0\}})\\
&= U\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1_{\{Y_i=1\}}\right)+(1-U)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1_{\{Y_i=0\}}\right)
\end{align}
which, by LLN, converges almost surely to $U\frac{1}{2}+(1-U)\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

$\{(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2), (X_3, Y_3), ...\}$ is stationary.


However, for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ such that $|S_n|>1$ we have
$$\frac{1}{|S_n|}\sum_{i\in S_n} X_i = U$$
and so $\frac{1}{|S_n|}\sum_{i\in S_n} X_i\rightarrow U$ almost surely. So we get almost sure convergence to a random variable $U$ with positive variance.

Thanks again for the answer, it is interesting that this can happen. I am still a bit confused about the notions of ergodicity and ergodicity-in-mean. If $(X_i, Y_i)$ are iid then the convergence trivially holds. I am looking for a notion such that the convergence holds even if they are (dependent) stochastic process. If they are stationary + mean ergodic, it is still not enough for the convergence. Is there some other notion that guarantees this convergence (without assuming some parametric model)?
